# Visual Studio Team Services .NET Core RC2 build and deploy stuck

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, rc2-cipher

I am trying to follow these instructions:

www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure

for building and deploying my .net core rc2 solution. However, I am getting stuck in in the 2nd part of the build step:

http://screencast.com/t/wcPPmNPhh6LR

This is the error I am getting:

```
    2016-06-27T20:41:30.8188890Z Executing the following command-line.    
    (workingFolder = C:\Builds\_work\3\s)
    2016-06-27T20:41:30.8188890Z cmd.exe /c "dotnet build"
    2016-06-27T20:41:30.8188890Z Error message highlight pattern: 
    2016-06-27T20:41:30.8188890Z Warning message highlight pattern: 
    2016-06-27T20:41:30.9126377Z Couldn't find 'project.json' in current directory
```

[image: The following is what my solution looks like in vs2015:]

Comment: Did you resolve the issue`?

Answer (score 0):

"dotnet build" command cannot find the "project.json" file in the current directory just as the error message indicates. Make sure you have the file in your project and it has been uploaded into version control. And then, in the "Advanced" setting panel of "dotnet build" task, set the "Working folder" to the path where the "project.json" file placed. Usually, it is the path of the project folder.

By the way, if you want to get a deployment package after build to deploy the project, you need to follow the second definition in the webpage you referred: [Define a deployment build](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure#define-a-deployment-build).